# warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c

I am confused to why this throws the error `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’`:

```
int x = 5;
int **y = &x;
printf("%d", y);
```

While this works?

```
int x = 5;
int *y = &x;
printf("%d", *y);
```

Comment: In your first example, do you mean `int *y` rather than `int **y`?

Comment: Neither are correct; the first for what @psmears said, the second because `%d` is for integers; an `int*` is not an integer. Use `%p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you declared `y` as a pointer to an integer in the second version, so the compiler gets a warm and fuzzy feeling that `*y` is a valid integer.

In the first version, `y` was declared as a pointer to a pointer of an integer (that's how I've always thought of it in my head anyway), so `*y` should resolve to a pointer of an integer rather than integer - the compiler is warning you that it might not line up with the `%d` in your `printf`.

Edited thanks to @KierBorromeo catching a silly typo on my part.

Comment: Is ```&d``` supposed to be a typo, sir?

Comment: @KierBorromeo Indeed it is, thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with the first version is that: the type of `y` is a **pointer to a pointer that points to an integer** while `&x` is an address which can be seen as **a pointer that points to an integer**. Obviously there is a mismatch out there.

In the second version, the type of `y` is **a pointer that points to an integer** therefore the program gets compiled without warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory.  You are passing a `int*` where an `int` is expected.

```
int x = 5;
int *y = &x;
printf("%d", y); // <-- y is an int* - ERROR
```

```
int x = 5;
int *y = &x;
printf("%d", *y); // <-- y is an int*, so *y is an int - OK
```

Comment: It's ```int **y = &x;``` if I'm not mistaken

Comment: That is a typo in the OP's code. `x` is an `int` and `&x` is an `int*`, but an `int*` cannot be assigned to an `int**`, so `y` has to be an `int*` instead of an`int**`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined `y` as a pointer to a pointer to int, so you can store the address of a pointer to int on `y`, but what you are trying to do is store the address of an `int`.

Comment: I suggest avoiding the phrase "double pointer"; it also means `double*`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I had not thought of it in that way.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your code, x is an integer, *y is a pointer to an integer and thus **y is a pointer to pointer which points to an integer. Its as good as saying `*y = &&x;`.